# Start flex elements off screen to animation into position

Tags: css, animation, flexbox

I'm having some trouble figuring out how best to get this animation to work.

I have two elements that are centered vertically inside of a flexbox layout, I want to get these elements to animate into their final positions by sliding in from off-screen, however, this seems to be giving me some unexpected results I assume because of their flex positioning. Any thoughts on how I can tackle this?

Here is a plunker showing the current state of things, I've slowed the animation down so you can see the dilemma and where I'm trying to take this.

```
.scroller-item-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  .scroll-animator {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-grow: 0;
    transform: translateY(100%);
    &:not(.pre-animated){
      animation-name: scrollItemIn;
      animation-duration: 1s;
      animation-timing-function: ease-out;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      &:last-of-type {
        animation-delay: 1300ms;
      }
    }
    &.leaving {
      animation-name: scrollItemOut;
      animation-duration: .3s;
      animation-timing-function: ease-out;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      transform: translateY(0%);
      &:last-of-type {
        animation-delay: 300ms;
      }
    }
    &:last-of-type {
      .scroller-item {
        margin-bottom: 0;
      }
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/MPyuTSjy2s5XWLk5EVVD?p=preview

Comment: Can't see any animation in that plnkr...?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to save, check again

Comment: And what is the actual issue?

Comment: So if you take the animation off of the element you can see the translate I was trying to use doesn't exactly get the elements to be totally off screen, I'm trying to figure out of there is a way to keep the flex positioning intact while also getting the elements to start fully offscreen (not just like 1000% positioned) so they can animate into place smoothly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using percent with `translate`, it is the elements own size it refers to, which means, if an element is 200px high, `translateY(100%)` will move it 200px (100% of its own height) down.

In this case you can use viewport units instead, i.e. `transform: translateY(100vh);`, which means it will position the element at the bottom of the viewport, no matter its height.

[Updated codepen](https://plnkr.co/edit/WV0arS5JRmUYjoTdR87A?p=preview)